# How to write my clickhouse sql query correctly?

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I have written a sql query:

```
WITH
  type = "id" AND match(value, '*** ID WAS ACTIVATED ***') as id_activ
SELECT
  multiIf(
        id_activ, 'id_activ',
        NULL) as case,
  date,
  value
FROM my.data.base
```

However it doesn't work. A problem occurs because of this part: match(value, '*** ID WAS ACTIVATED ***'). When i try this, it works perfectly:

```
WITH
  type = "id" AND value LIKE '%*** ID WAS ACTIVATED ***%' as id_activ
SELECT
  multiIf(
        id_activ, 'id_activ',
        NULL) as case,
  date,
  value
FROM my.data.base
```

Here is a full message with that pattern that I use in match:

```
*** ID WAS ACTIVATED *** : Values expired
```

How could i fix it and write query with match right?

Same thing with query which has square brackets in it:

```
WITH
  type = "id" AND match(value, 'Values processed [NUMBERS]') as id_number
SELECT
  multiIf(
        id_number, 'id_number',
        NULL) as case,
  date,
  value
FROM my.data.base
```

Answer (score 0):

`match()` is matching regular expression

"Equivalent" to

```sql
LIKE '%*** ID WAS ACTIVATED ***%'
```

is

```sql
match(value, '.*\*\*\* ID WAS ACTIVATED \*\*\*.*')
```

https://regex101.com/r/XkRmEY/1